# HTML Bootstrap table with fixed header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have one HTML bootstrap table which is having more than 15 columns, so I enabled overflow auto and it is having both vertical and horizontal scrolling. I am trying to fix the header part but I am not able to do that just because of table width is more than 100% and I can't specify columns width over 100%. can anyone help out to resolve this issue with pure HTML and CSS, I don't want to use any library or script code

Note: I am rendering this table in Angular5

Comment: Could you provide us with an [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Year</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
</tr>
        <tr>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
    <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
   width: 100%;
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

thead th {
    height: 30px;

    /*text-align: left;*/
}

tbody {
    height: 120px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
    /* fallback */
}


tbody td, thead th {
    width: 19.2%;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is example which is help you [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7/)

Comment: Here each column is defined with specific width divided by 100, but in my case table width is more than 100%

Comment: You can set your table with 100% and set scroll y and x, hope you understand.